# How does tinypng.org compress PNG files?

Tags: compression, png

http://tinypng.org/ is a great service, they optimized my png images by ~67%. How does their service work? How can they minimize size and quality of pictures still remains the same?

Comment: There are close votes on this question.  I was thinking of casting a vote, but it's really hard to justify that when all of the votes are for different reasons.  Personally, I think it's off topic.  It's not not a real question.  There are 2 very real questions.

Comment: PNG is lossless. There are existing tools for [optimized compression](http://www.google.de/search?q=png+compression+optimize). Should your overly broad question be about the algorithm or format, then there's also the [PNG spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/)

Answer (score 76, accepted):

The answer's right on that web page:

> When you upload a PNG (Portable Network Graphics) file, similar
>   colours in your image are combined. This technique is called
>   “quantisation”. Because the number of colours is reduced, 24-bit PNG
>   files can be converted to much smaller 8-bit indexed colour images.
>   All unnecessary metadata is stripped too. The result: tiny 8-bit PNG
>   files with 100% support for transparency. Have your cake and eat it
>   too!

It turns 24-bit RGB files into palettized 8-bit ones. You lose some color depth, but for small images it's often imperceptible.

You can do the same thing manually on the command line with this awesome tool:
http://pngquant.org/

Comment: when I tried to execute this exe from command prompt in Windows . it says "'pngquant' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file." do you have any idea on this?

Comment: @user270014 - You must be inside directory which actually contains that exe file. Use cd C:\path\to\pngquant

Comment: Is tinyPNG lossy or lossless?

Comment: @ShubhamBadal: This color reduction process is lossy relative to the original image data.

Comment: Thank you for the alternative! TinyPNG plus optimization (e.g. [`image_optim`](https://github.com/toy/image_optim)) seems to produce the best results, but `pngquant` is nice and easy to script.

Comment: I've made a test. Use a 8-bit PNG file 1.2MB, and tinypng compress it into 300K. It seems it's NOT to turn 24-bit RGB file into a 8 bit one