# Pillow png compressing

Tags: django, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

Im making a simple app that able to compress images with jpeg and png format using Pillow library, python3 and Django. Made a simple view that able to identify formats, save compress images and give some statistics of compressing. With images in jpeg format it works really fine, i got compressicons close to 70-80% of original size, and it works really fast, but if i upload png i works much worse. Compression takes a long time, and it only 3-5% of original size. Trying to find some ways to upgrade compress script, and stuck on it.

Right now ive got this script in my compress django view:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404, reverse
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate, logout
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.contrib import auth
from .forms import InputForm, SignUpForm, LoginForm, FTPForm
import os
import sys
from PIL import Image
from .models import image, imagenew, FTPinput
from django.views import View
import datetime
from django.utils import timezone
import piexif


class BasicUploadView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        return render(self.request, 'main/index.html', {})

    def post(self, request):
        form = InputForm(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():              
            photo = form.save(commit=False)
            photo.name = photo.image.name
            photo.delete_time = timezone.now() + datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
            photo.user = request.user
            photo.size = photo.image.size
            photo = form.save()

            name = (photo.name).replace(' ', '_')

            picture = Image.open(photo.image)

            if picture.mode in ('RGB'):
                piexif.remove('/home/andrey/sjimalka' + photo.image.url)
                picture.save('media/new/'+name,"JPEG",optimize=True,quality=75)
                newpic = 'new/'+name
                new = imagenew.objects.create(
                    name = name,
                    image = newpic,
                    delete_time = timezone.now() + datetime.timedelta(hours=1),
                    user = request.user,
                )
                if new.image.size < photo.image.size:
                    diff = round((new.image.size-photo.image.size)/float(photo.image.size)*100, 2)
                else:
                    diff = str(round((new.image.size-photo.image.size)/float(photo.image.size)*100, 2))+' Не удалось сжать файл'
                oldsize = round(photo.image.size/1000000, 2)
                newsize = round(new.image.size/1000000, 2)
                id = new.pk
                imagenew.objects.filter(pk=id).update(size=new.image.size)
            elif picture.mode != ('RGB'):
                picture.save('media/new/'+name,"PNG", optimize=True, quality=75)
                newpic = 'new/'+name
                new = imagenew.objects.create(
                    name = name,
                    image = newpic,
                    delete_time = timezone.now() + datetime.timedelta(hours=1),
                    user = request.user,
                )
                if new.image.size < photo.image.size:
                    diff = round((new.image.size-photo.image.size)/float(photo.image.size)*100, 2)
                else:
                    diff = str(round((new.image.size-photo.image.size)/float(photo.image.size)*100, 2))+' Не удалось сжать файл'

                oldsize = round(photo.image.size/1000000, 2)
                newsize = round(new.image.size/1000000, 2)
                id = new.pk
                imagenew.objects.filter(pk=id).update(size=new.image.size)

            data = {'is_valid': True, 'name': new.image.name, 'url': new.image.url, 'diff': diff,
                'oldsize':oldsize, 'newsize':newsize,}
        else:
            alert = 'Данный формат не поддерживается. Пожалуйста загрузите картинки форматов png или jpg(jpeg)'
            data = {'is_valid': False, 'name': alert,}
        return JsonResponse(data)
```

The question: is there any ways to make script with png upload work faster, and (that much more important) make png size compressions closer to jpeg? Maybe i should use another python library?

Comment: Try redis and celery...But not work correctly if you server base in windows... You need linux. With celery you create a task...maybe to compression process .....

Comment: i already use it. How could it help in compressing?

Comment: With celery you create a task...maybe to compression process...

Comment: I can give you example of code if you want

Comment: ive got some compression tasks in celery, but it works with the same compress script. It compressing png as bad as simple django view. I should improve the script, that celery or django-view use to compress

Comment: I recommend you to use ajax for get form after post, Celery task for compress process...when i show your code you use all in your view...you must separate script of compression to celery task and call them when post form

Comment: @AndrejVilenskij PNG is a lossless compression format, whereas JPEG is a lossy compression format. Obviously, PNG won't compress an image as much as JPEG can.

Comment: @xyres how tinypng works then? They compressing same png files with 50-60%

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> how tinypng works then? They compressing same png files with 50-60%

They probably reduce the colour palette from 24-bit to 8-bit. Here's a detailed answer about that - https://stackoverflow.com/a/12146901/1925257

#### Basic method

You can try that in Pillow like this:

```
picture_8bit = picture.convert(
    mode='P', # use mode='PA' for transparency
    palette=Image.ADAPTIVE
)
picture_8bit.save(...) # do as usual
```

This should work similar to what tinypng does.

If you don't want transparency, it's better to first convert `RGBA` to `RGB` and then to `P` mode:

```
picture_rgb = picture.convert(mode='RGB') # convert RGBA to RGB
picture_8bit = picture_rgb.convert(mode='P', ...)
```

#### Getting better results

Calling `convert()` as shown above will actually call `quantize()` in the background and [`Median Cut`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_cut) algorithm will be used by default for reducing the colour palette.

In some cases, you'll get better results with other algorithms such as `MAXCOVERAGE`. To use a different algorithm, you can just call the [`quantize()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.quantize) method directly:

```
picture_rgb = picture.convert(mode='RGB') # convert RGBA to RGB
picture_8bit = picture.quantize(colors=256, method=Image.MAXCOVERAGE)
```

---

You have to understand that downsizing the colour palette means that if the image has lots of colours, you will be losing most of them because 8-bit can only contain 256 colours.

Comment: Why should someone use `PA` for transparency ? With an input PNG with transparency, it is compressed and kept with `P` only. If I tried `PA`, I got `OSError: cannot write mode PA as PNG`.

Answer (score 4):

The document of **[Pillow Image.quatize](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.quantize)** displays a more convenient way to compress png files. In a personal experiment, the following code could make png about 70% compression of the original size, which is also close to the result created by **ImageMagick**.

```
# Image.quantize(colors=256, method=None, kmeans=0, palette=None)
# method: 0 = median cut; 1 = maximum coverage; 2 = fast octree
img = img.quantize(method=2)
```